# Symfony, set locale using the domain tld, force it if not in a list

Tags: symfony, routes, internationalization

`Hi, I'm trying to set locale using the tld of the domain e.g.

www.domain.es => locale = es

www.domain.fr => locale = fr

using this route

```
/app/config/routing.yml

home_www:
    resource: "@AppWwwBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host:     "www.domain.{_locale}"
    prefix:   /
```

But the problem comes with the www.domain.com, how can I force the locale to "en" ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting `home_www:defaults:_locale` to `en`?

Comment: Well, could work, but will not solve

www.domain.com.ar  => locale es_AR
By example

Comment: In fact I need to map tld (.es, .com, .fr, .com.ar) to locales ('es_ES', 'en_EN', 'fr_FR','es_AR')

Comment: I've never used the host section so I'm not sure but I think this would be best achieved using an event listener listening for the `kernel.request`, then working out and settings the `_locale` from the given `tld`. Like I said though, I could be wrong.

Comment: yep, I would prefer to use a subdomain or even a path in url, but I can't decide this

Comment: I guess using a listener with a service to do the decision making would be the best approach for you then.

Comment: Done! I've found this posts which helped me a lot

http://donna-oberes.blogspot.com.es/2014/12/localization-based-on-domain-name.html